# How do I change the color of the line highlight in vscode when using findNext

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have customized my theme in vscode to use the lineHighlight color as follows...

```
    "editor.lineHighlightBackground": "#3c3c3c",
```

This change works, with the exception of when I use find next.

If I open the find window, and end a value that matches with multiple lines, and then use the findNext command to cycle through them, there is a line highlight that draws, but it is not using the line highlight that I specified.

I have looked through the vscode theme colors documentation and they only specify the following line highlight values..

```
editor.lineHighlightBackground: Background color for the highlight of line at the cursor position.
editor.lineHighlightBorder: Background color for the border around the line at the cursor position.
```

How can I change the color of the line highlight when using find next?

Comment: background colors must have a transparent component, add an additional byte

Comment: @rioV8 That makes no difference. Read the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

`"editor.rangeHighlightBackground": "#ff0000"`

> `editor.findRangeHighlightBackground`: Color the range limiting the
> search (Enable 'Find in Selection' in the find widget). The color must
> not be opaque so as not to hide underlying decorations.

It is more specific than a line highlight so it is the one applied.  It applies whether the `Find in Selection` option is enabled or not - not sure why it implies that.